# How to check for inclusion of multisets?

Tags: python

A multiset is a set which allows for repeats. So a submultiset is one that includes fewer or the same number of each element.

Is there a way to represent and operate on multisets in Python?

Sets obviously don't work for this. For example, the code below returns True, which is not what I want because it takes the repeated letters as one letter.

```
{'h','h','h','e','e','e','e'}.issubset({'h', 'e'})
```

Comment: What do you mean, "take the repeated letters as one letter"? You are aware that a set cannot contain duplicate items?

Comment: That set contains two elements ('h' and 'e'). You can't repeat items in a set, because a set consists of unique elements. IOW, you can add 'h' to the set a billion times and you'll still end up with a set with a single element.

Answer (score 4):

The most simple representation for a [multiset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) in Python which I know of is a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object. It supports basic set operations (`+`, `-`, `&`, `|`), and although it doesn't have methods like `issubset` you can probably mimic those with the more simple operations.

For example,

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> big = Counter(list('hhheeee'))
>>> small = Counter(list('he'))
>>> big
Counter({'e': 4, 'h': 3})
```

To check if our Counter "multiset" `Counter({'e': 4, 'h': 3})` is a subset of the multiset `Counter({'e': 1, 'h': 1})`,

```
>>> not bool(big-small)
False
```

Or we could verify things like the well-known addition rule,

[image]

```
>>> big | small == big + small - (big & small)
True
```

It is worth noting that a `Counter` does *not* have the same breadth of interface as something like a C++ `std::multiset`, so interpreting it as an equivalent structure wouldn't be a good idea. It can be handy for some operations however.